# Creating xml from directory structure

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, directory

I have a directory with files and sub directories with files and want to create xml from them. here is my folder structure:

```
C:\inputdata folder contains:
C:\inputdata\file1.txt
C:\inputdata\picture1.jpg
C:\inputdata\subfolder\picture2.jpg
C:\inputdata\subfolder\file2.txt
C:\inputdata\subfolder\anotherfolder \file3.txt
C:\inputdata\anotherfolder\
```

and i want to generate this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serverfiles>
     <file name="picture1.jpg"/>
     <file name="file1.txt"/>
     <folder name="subfolder">
          <file name="picture2.jpg"/>
          <file name="file2.txt"/>
          <folder name="anotherfolder">
               <file name="file3.txt"/>
          </folder>
     </folder>
     <folder name="anotherfolder">
     </folder>
</serverfiles>
```

I have written following console app but i have two problems.

1. this produces the attached screenshot xml which is not exactly as above xml in terms of structure.
2. is there a way I could sort this with the name attribute with my code.

can someone please point me to right direction of how to do this please:

```
    private const string folderLocation = @"c:\inputdata";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderLocation);


        var doc = new XDocument(CREATEXML(dir));

        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }

  private static XElement CREATEXML(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        //get directories
        var xmlInfo = new XElement("serverfiles", new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));

        //get all the files first
        foreach(var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
        }

        //get subdirectories
        foreach(var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(CREATEXML(subDir));
        }

        return xmlInfo;

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more method that will handle subdirectories

```
private static XElement CreateXML(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        var xmlInfo = new XElement("serverfiles");
        //get all the files first
        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
        }
        //get subdirectories
        foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(CreateSubdirectoryXML(subDir));
        }
        return xmlInfo;
    }

    private static XElement CreateSubdirectoryXML(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        //get directories
        var xmlInfo = new XElement("folder", new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));
        //get all the files first
        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
        }
        //get subdirectories
        foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(CreateSubdirectoryXML(subDir));
        }
        return xmlInfo;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Added sorting:

```
private static XElement CreateXML(DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            var xmlInfo = new XElement("serverfiles");
            //get all the files first
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
            }
            //get subdirectories
            var subdirectories = dir.GetDirectories().ToList().OrderBy(d => d.Name);
            foreach (var subDir in subdirectories)
            {
                xmlInfo.Add(CreateSubdirectoryXML(subDir));
            }
            return xmlInfo;
        }

        private static XElement CreateSubdirectoryXML(DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            //get directories
            var xmlInfo = new XElement("folder", new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));
            //get all the files first
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
            }
            //get subdirectories
            var subdirectories = dir.GetDirectories().ToList().OrderBy(d => d.Name);
            foreach (var subDir in subdirectories)
            {
                xmlInfo.Add(CreateSubdirectoryXML(subDir));
            }
            return xmlInfo;
        }
```

Comment: thanks that eliminated the first folder name...how do i sort it now should i put it in a dictionary<string, string> or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

Nearly there: just some small edits to your code are what you need.

```
    private const string folderLocation = @"c:\inputdata";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderLocation);

        // makes everything wrapped in an XElement called serverfiles.
        // Also a declaration as specified (sorry about the standalone status:
        // it's required in the XDeclaration constructor)    
        var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
             CREATEXML(dir));

        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }

  private static XElement CREATEXML(DirectoryInfo dir, bool writingServerFiles = true)
    {
        //get directories
        var xmlInfo = new XElement(writingServerFiles ? "serverfiles" : "folder", writingServerFiles ? null : new XAttribute("name", dir.Name)); //fixes your small isue (making the root serverfiles and the rest folder, and serverfiles not having a name XAttribute)

        //get all the files first
        foreach(var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
        }
            //get subdirectories
        foreach(var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(CREATEXML(subDir), false);
        }
        return xmlInfo;

    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. the only issue i have now is it lists "inputdata" folder. also how would i go about sorting them by name?

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic No, it just wraps everything. As requested.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic: If you want to sort by name, you have to scan the directories and store them in a tree structure, do the sort, and then output the XML. You can't do the scan, sort, and XML streaming in a single operation.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic Yeah, it's missing the indentation! Gasp! Terrible! And that's not the actual output: the output would have an XML declaration. ;)

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic you are right your solution eliminated this :p

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic Oh right, missed that his main directory didn't need a folder element.  Sorry.

Comment: NikolaDavidovic and ofstream thanks for the answers and advice if i want to store it in tree structure what do i use dictionary or list or generics?

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic I wasn't angry, I just failed to see a glaring issue. Didn't mean to get angry.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I do usually, it's just that I copied his method naming. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution can be better

```
        //get directories
        var xmlInfo = new XElement("folder",                 
            new XElement("name", dir.Name),
            new XElement("lastModify", dir.LastWriteTime),
            new XElement("Attributes", dir.Attributes));

        //get subdirectories
        foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(CREATEXML(subDir));
        }

        //get all the files
        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("File",
                new XElement("name", file.Name),
                new XElement("size", file.Length),
                new XElement("lastModify", file.LastWriteTime),
                new XElement("Attributes", file.Attributes.ToString())));
        }
        return xmlInfo;
```